# Image enhancement solution

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a large number of images of the following type/qualitiy:

[image]

What I would like to do is:

- remove the noise (without affecting the rest of the image)
- enhance the line-work

Doing it manually with brush/eraser is not an option as there are too many images. **What operations/filters can be used to enhance these images?**

Comment: try out gimp at http://www.gimp.org/ - it's a photoshop  imitation

Comment: @RachelGallen: Did you notice that the OP wrote *"Doing it manually ... is not an option"*?!? Your comment would be more helpful if you could outline how to use Gimp in an automatic, scripted way and not manually...

Answer (score 3):

The most easy way to do this is probably ImageMagick. Since you need to apply the operation on a large number of images, you can write a script to do it.

You can start playing with the following *image operators* available for ImageMagick's `convert` command:

- **`-threshold`**:
  This operator applies a simultaneous black/white threshold to the input image.
- **`-blur`**:
  This operator reduces noise and detail levels of the input image.
- **`-sharpen`**:
  This operator sharpens the input image.
- **`-black-threshold`**:
  This operator forces to black all pixels ***below*** the threshold while leaving all pixels at or above the threshold unchanged.
- **`-white-threshold`**:
  This operator forces to white all pixels ***above*** the threshold while leaving all pixels at or above the threshold unchanged.
- **`-morphology`**:
  This operator can modify an image with various *'methods'*. Below are examples for the methods `dilate` and `erode` (there are more than 2 dozen different methods available). Each method can apply different *'kernels'*. Below are examples for the kernels `diamond` and `kirsch` (there are almost 3 dozen different kernels available).

You can apply a single one of them, or a suitable combination of several of them within one command line. Play with a few variations to see which suits you best.

### *'threshold'*

Here are a few command examples with their output:

```
convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/15lOG.png \
 -threshold 50%                      \
  50pc-threshold.png

convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/15lOG.png \
 -threshold 85%                      \
  85pc-threshold.png
```

The first image (on the left) shows the first command's output. The second image is the result of the second command:

[image] [image]

### *'threshold'* plus *'blur'*

In order to reduce the sharp black/white borders you may want to "make it easier to the eyes" and apply some additional blurring to the output:

```
convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/15lOG.png \
 -threshold 85%                      \
 -blur 2x1                           \
  85pc-threshold+blur-2x1.png
```

### *'threshold'* plus *'blur'* plus *'sharpen'*

For the output see next image (to the left). After blurring, you can apply another round (or two) of processing: sharpening again. Here is a command:

```
convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/15lOG.png \
 -threshold 85%                      \
 -blur 2x1                           \
 -sharpen 0x3                        \
 -sharpen 0x3                        \
  85pc-threshold+blur-2x1+sharpen-0x3+sharpen-0x3.png
```

The respective output is the last image (to the right).

[image] [image]

### *'white-threshold'* and *'black-threshold'*

The following two commands demonstrate the use of `-white-threshold 50%` and of `-black-threshold 50%`:

```
convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/15lOG.png \
 -white-threshold 50%                \
  white-threshold-50pc.png

convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/15lOG.png \
 -black-threshold 50%                \
  black-threshold-50pc.png
```

The following two images show the resulting images:

[image] [image]

The same as above, but with different threshold values:

```
convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/15lOG.png \
 -white-threshold 85%                \
  white-threshold-85pc.png

convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/15lOG.png \
 -black-threshold 85%                \
  black-threshold-85pc.png
```

[image] [image]

### *'black-threshold'* plus *'black-threshold'*

Combining both threshold operations:

```
convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/15lOG.png \
 -black-threshold 85%                \
 -white-threshold 85%                \
  black-threshold-85pc+white-threshold-85pc.png


convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/15lOG.png \
 -white-threshold 85%                \
 -black-threshold 85%                \
  white-threshold-85pc+black-threshold-85pc.png
```

[image] [image]

If you look closely, you'll easily see that the last two example commands' outputs are not different (and they are also identical to the second command's output).

In order to possibly get better results than from above commands, you'll have to play with some variations of the respective parameters (do not always use `85%`...).

### Additional *'thinning'* with `-morphology`

We can apply some *'thinning'* to one of the current results. I'll pick the fourth image/command from the top:

```
convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/15lOG.png \
 -threshold 85%                      \
 -blur 2x1                           \
 -sharpen 0x3                        \
 -sharpen 0x3                        \
 -morphology erode diamond           \
  85pc-threshold+blur-2x1+sharpen-0x3+sharpen-0x3+erode+diamond.png
```

The added `-morphology erode diamond` uses a 'diamond' shaped 'kernel' to erode white areas -- which means the black lines get thicker. You can see this in the first image below. But this is not the effect we desired. That's why we apply a `-negate` operation before the `-morphology` one, and another `-negate` afterwards:

```
convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/15lOG.png \
 -threshold 85%                      \
 -blur 2x1                           \
 -sharpen 0x3                        \
 -sharpen 0x3                        \
 -negate                             \
 -morphology erode diamond           \
 -negate                             \
  85pc-threshold+blur-2x1+sharpen-0x3+sharpen-0x3+negate+erode+diamond.png
```

Both output images are below:

[image] [image]

Instead of using `erode` (which erodes white) we can use `dilate` (which dilates white):

```
convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/15lOG.png \
 -threshold 85%                      \
 -blur 2x1                           \
 -sharpen 0x3                        \
 -sharpen 0x3                        \
 -morphology dilate diamond          \
  85pc-threshold+blur-2x1+sharpen-0x3+sharpen-0x3+dilate+diamond.png
```

To see a list of all built-in kernel shapes, run `convert -list kernel`. Instead of a diamond-shaped morphology kernel, we can experiment with a 'kirsch':

```
convert                              \
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/15lOG.png \
 -threshold 85%                      \
 -blur 2x1                           \
 -sharpen 0x3                        \
 -sharpen 0x3                        \
 -morphology dilate kirsch           \
  85pc-threshold+blur-2x1+sharpen-0x3+sharpen-0x3+dilate+kirsch.png
```

[image] [image]

To get a complete set of what all available kernels can do, you could try this:

```
for i in $(convert -list kernel); do    \
   convert                              \
     https://i.stack.imgur.com/15lOG.png  \
    -threshold 85%                       \
    -blur 2x1                            \
    -sharpen 0x3                         \
    -sharpen 0x3                         \
    -morphology dilate ${i}              \
     85pc-threshold+blur-2x1+sharpen-0x3+sharpen-0x3+dilate+${i}-kernel.png \
done
```

To learn more about the various `-morphology` operations, see here: [ImageMagick Examples -- Morphology of Shapes](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/). To get a complete list of morphology kernels, run `convert -list morphology`.

---

---

<sub>There are many more processing options available in ImageMagick. You should explore them yourself... Start here to learn about them:</sub>

1. <sub>[ImageMagick Command-Line Options](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php)</sub>
2. <sub>[ImageMagick Usage Examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/)</sub>
3. <sub>[ImageMagick Usage Examples -- Reference Index](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/reference.html)</sub>

Comment: This is great, but the lines in the output appear quite thick now. Any other options to get it closer to the original?

Comment: Did you play around yourself with the parameters? Or are you waiting for a ready-made command line, designed by someone who has no clue about what's on your mind for an acceptable result?!? (The very least you could do, is add a sample result image of what you achieve when doing it manually...)

Comment: Great answer with sound advice! Have my vote. You could maybe try adding a `-morphology erode octagon` just before the output filename to *thin* the outline, or with `octagon:3` for greater effect.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Please feel free to edit my answer -- or better: add your own answer using this additional operation. BTW, I guess that simply adding a `-morphology erode` will not work without an additional `-negate`. Also `octagon` is probably too big a kernel to use here. (If you add an answer, I'd recommend it to the OP for 'accepting' :-)

Comment: Apart from typos, I wouldn't normally interfere with or edit another person's answer, least of all yours :-) I wasn't at my computer and when I suggested morphological thinnning/erosion to try and help out the OP after the comment that the lines were *too thick*, so it was more of an idea/suggestion than anything. Well done and thank you for taking the time to incorporate it - let's hope your lucky OP accepts this for the great answer it is.